# Timer Using useEffect in React Js

Tags: reactjs

```
import { useState ,useEffect} from "react";

function Timer(){
    const [Time,setTime]=useState(new Date());
    const [curTime,setCurtime]=useState(new Date());
    const [isstart,setisStart]=useState(false);

    function handleClick(){
        setCurtime(new Date());
        setisStart(!isstart);
        if(isstart===false){
            setTime(new Date());
            setCurtime(new Date());
            return;
        }
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const idx=setInterval(setTime(new Date()),1000);
        return()=>{
            clearInterval(idx);
        }
    },[handleClick])

    return(
        <>
          {  console.log(Time,curTime)}
            {Math.floor((Time-curTime)/1000/60/60)%24+':'+Math.floor((Time-curTime)/1000/60)%60+':'+Math.floor((Time-curTime)/1000)%60}
            <button onClick={handleClick}>{!isstart?'Start':'Stop'}</button><br/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Timer;
```

I wanted to start the timer after click on the button but instead it starts whenever I reload the page and when I click on the button the timer resets.

Answer (score 0):

React effects will always run at least once. Your `useEffect` hook is executing during the initial render, which starts the interval automatically.

If you would like to defer starting the interval, you can use a flag to indicate whether the timer should be running or not.

Here is a simple example:

```js
export default function Timer() {
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRunning) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => setCurrentTime(new Date()), 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [isRunning, setCurrentTime]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{currentTime.toISOString()}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setIsRunning((running) => !running)}>
        {isRunning ? "Stop" : "Start"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```